# Using EFS csi driver, do I create multiple PV for each path with the same volumeHandle and how do I specify which PV for the PVC?

Tags: kubernetes, persistent-volumes, persistent-volume-claims, amazon-efs

See below I have directories in EFS - `data` and `logs`. Do I need to create a different PV if I need to use a subpath? And if I do, how do I specify the PV to use for the PVC?

```
---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-pv-data
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    {{/*    same EFS ID*/}}
    volumeHandle: fs-ABC1234
    volumeAttributes:
      path: /data

---
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: efs-pv-logs
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    {{/*    same EFS ID*/}}
    volumeHandle: fs-ABC1234
    volumeAttributes:
      path: /logs

---

apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: efs-claim-data
  namespace: my-app
spec:
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  storageClassName: "efs-sc"
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
```

Comment: I tested it and looks like this is not possible. But the PV and the PVC status says it is `Bound`. To me that status means it is ready and can be mounted to the pod or containers. But when mounting the volume to the container, it will get an error `Unable to mount volumes ...`

Comment: Do I need to create a different StorageClass for each path?

Answer (score 0):

I've confirmed that it works with an almost identical setup. It looks like what you're missing is the `volumeName` attribute of the pvc, which binds it to a specific pv.

e.g:

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: PersistentVolumeClaim
metadata:
  name: testpvc
  namespace: apis
spec:
  resources:
    requests:
      storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  storageClassName: efs-sc
accessModes:
  - ReadWriteMany
volumeName: example-pv
```

Also, I'm using EFS AccessPoints so that if the path does not exist on the EFS filesystem it can be created automatically (more info [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/efs/latest/ug/efs-access-points.html#enforce-root-directory-access-point)).

It can be then used like that in the pv, instead of using path:

```
kind: PersistentVolume
metadata:
  name: example-pv
spec:
  capacity:
    storage: 5Gi
  volumeMode: Filesystem
  accessModes:
    - ReadWriteMany
  persistentVolumeReclaimPolicy: Retain
  storageClassName: efs-sc
  csi:
    driver: efs.csi.aws.com
    volumeHandle: fs-xxxxxxxxxx::fsap:xxxxxxxxx
```

I hope people find this useful because I've struggled with provisioning a big amount of pvs and pvcs relating to the same efs.